# A confusion about swift syntax “String.localizedStandardCompare”

Tags: swift, syntax

I am reading "Advanced Swift" currently.
It seems "a".localizedStandardCompare("b") can also be written as String.localizedStandardCompare("a")("b")
I tried in a Playground and the two expression gave the same result.

I just don't very understand the syntax of String.localizedStandardCompare("a")("b") since its declaration is

```
func localizedStandardCompare<T>(_ string: T) -> ComparisonResult where T : StringProtocol
```

Comment: Just figured it out! String.localizedStandardCompare's delaration should be localizedStandardCompare<T>(self: String)->(_ string: T) -> ComparisonResult where T : StringProtocol.

Comment: See https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/.